# How to use binary operators "<" and ">" for comparing objects in Java?

Tags: java, comparable

Consider having this class in Java:

```
public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
    private int someValue;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Foo o) {
        if (this.someValue < o.someValue) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.someValue == o.someValue) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo(someValue);
Foo foo2 = new Foo(someAnotherValue);
if (foo1 < foo2) {
   // do something
}
```

But the IDE is giving me an error which is: "Bad operand types for binary operation '<' first type: Foo, second type: Foo"

May you please tell me what is wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: You can't. Those operators can only be used with numeric types. `Foo` is not a numeric type.

Comment: Java (unlike some other languages), does **not** support operator overloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing the `Comparable` interface is a good first step to being able to compare your objects properly.  However, that doesn't allow you to use the `<` and `>` comparison operators as if the operators were overloaded.  You just need to call your `compareTo` method.

```
if (foo1.compareTo(foo2) < 0) {
```